# Remove duplicates from NSArray case insensitively using NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, duplicates, case-insensitive

```
NSArray*arr = @[@"ram",@"Ram",@"vinoth",@"kiran",@"kiran"];
NSSet* uniqueName = [[NSSet alloc]initWithArray:arr];
NSLog(@"Unique Names :%@",uniqueName);
```

**Output:**

[image]

but i need the output as

[image]

Comment: If there are duplicates in case but otherwise the same work how do you want to choose which one to keep?

Answer (score 3):

You could first convert them all to lowercase strings.

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"ram",@"Ram",@"vinoth",@"kiran",@"kiran"];
NSArray *lowerCaseArr = [arr valueForKey:@"lowercaseString"];
NSSet* uniqueName = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:lowerCaseArr];
NSLog(@"Unique Names :%@",uniqueName);
```

Unique Names :{(
    ram,
    kiran,
    vinoth
)}

Comment: Concise! This assumes the OP wants to lowercase all the values, the question is not well formed in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ram",@"ram", nil]; //this is your array
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //make a nsmutableArray 
for (int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
    [arr1 addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i]lowercaseString]];
}
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:(NSArray*)arr1];//this set has unique values
```

Comment: I never knew about NSSet. "Remember that NSSet are composed of unique elements, so this serves as a convenient way to remove all duplicates in an array" +1

Answer (score 1):

This will always preserve casing form that was existing in your original container (although it's undefined which casing):

```
NSArray<NSString*>* input = ...
NSMutableDictionary* tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString* s in input) {
    [tmp setObject:s forKey:[s lowercaseString]];
}
return [tmp allValues];
```

Answer (score 0):

#Updated
Using this you remove uppercase string from your array.

```
 NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ram",@"Ram",@"vinoth",@"kiran", nil];
 NSMutableArray *arrCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (int index = 0 ; index<arr.count; index++) {
    NSUInteger count = [[[[arr objectAtIndex:index] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] length];
    if (count == 0) {
        [arrCopy addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
  }
  NSLog(@"Print Mutable Copy %@",arrCopy);
```

Comment: check out my question I need to find it case insensitively

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutable array the same size as `arr`.  Fill it with `lowercaseString` versions of each element of `arr`.  Make the set out of that.

Comment: The question is not about changing the case of the array members.

Comment: @Zaph - As I read it, the question is about creating a set of strings that are unique if case is disregarded.  By creating an array of proxy strings that have case removed as a consideration, the resulting set should have the values that the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
NSArray *copyArray = [mainArray copy];
NSInteger index = [copyArray count] - 1;
for (id object in [copyArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if ([mainArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [mainArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
copyArray=nil;
```